# System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException [4484] Designer process terminated unexpectedly?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I created a class to monitor properties for changes and trigger the INotifyPropertyChanged event

however when a class using its added to a WPF control the designer crashes with an unhandled exception of

> System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException [4484] Designer process
>   terminated unexpectedly!

anyone know why?

```
public interface IObservableValue<T>:INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public class ObservableProperty<T> : IObservableValue<T>
{
    public static implicit operator T(ObservableProperty<T> obj)
    {
        return obj.Value;
    }

    public ObservableProperty()
        :this(default(T))
    {
    }
    public ObservableProperty(T value)
    {
        val = value;
        CheckInterface(val, true);
    }


    T val;

    public T Value
    {
        get { return val; }
        set
        {
            if (!val.Equals(value))
            {
                OnPropertyChanging(changingArgs);

                CheckInterface( val, false);
                val = value;
                CheckInterface( val, true);

                OnPropertyChanged(changedArgs);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool HasValue
    {
        get { return val!=null; }
    }


    protected void CheckInterface<TValue>(TValue value, bool add)
    {
        INotifyPropertyChanging inc = value as INotifyPropertyChanging;
        if (inc != null)
        {
            if (add)
                inc.PropertyChanging += new PropertyChangingEventHandler(val_PropertyChanging);
            else
                inc.PropertyChanging -= new PropertyChangingEventHandler(val_PropertyChanging);
        }

        INotifyPropertyChanged inpc = value as INotifyPropertyChanged;
        if (inpc != null)
        {
            if (add)
                inpc.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(val_PropertyChanged);
            else
                inpc.PropertyChanged -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(val_PropertyChanged);
        }
        INotifyCollectionChanged incc = value as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (incc != null)
        {
            if (add)
                incc.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(val_CollectionChanged);
            else
                incc.CollectionChanged -= new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(val_CollectionChanged);
        }
    }


    void val_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(changedArgs);
    }
    void val_PropertyChanging(object sender, PropertyChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanging(changingArgs);
    }
    void val_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(changedArgs);
    }
    void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs changed)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, changed);
    }
    void OnPropertyChanging(PropertyChangingEventArgs changed)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanging;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, changed);
    }


    private static PropertyChangedEventArgs changedArgs = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value");
    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs changingArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs("Value");

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio - Designer process terminated unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001812/visual-studio-designer-process-terminated-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very Odd but restarting VS2012 Fixed it

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I see is that this line

```
if(!val.Equals(value))
```

will throw a `NullReferenceException` when `val` is null.  Also, I bet the designer uses the default constructor for the class, which means that `val` is null in the designer, thus the value setter throws an exception.

Comment: Equals should not be used in the context of generics. Rather use `EquatabilityComparer<T>.Default.Compare`.

Comment: Compare doesn't exist in that class, do you mean equals?

Comment: However that can't be the issue as for something to trigger that code it would have to be bound to the setter of the Value Property, the default constructor sets the attribute directly not using the property logic, and it was at the point of adding the object to the controls resource dictionary. also in this instance the generic type was double so null wasn't a possible value. as shutting down every open copy of VS2012 seems to have cured it i think it must have been something gone peculiar in the designer