# Visual Studio - Designer process terminated unexpectedly

Tags: visual-studio

After opening project (new or old) Visual Studio shows warning *"Designer terminated unexpectedly"* (can see in the picture below). What could cause this error? And how to fix that?

[image]

I clicked "click here to reload the designer" and it shows the same error.

Comment: I've tried to find any solution on the internet.. lots of people had the same problem, but nothing had helped me to solve that..

Comment: if it's VS2015, make sure you are using **Update 2** ([download link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx)). good luck...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and found out that my Oracle VirtualBox causes the issue.
My Visual Studio runs in a virtual Windows 10 enviroment.

After I disabled "Enable 3D Acceleration" in options Display, my Visual Studio Designer worked fine again.

Comment: This worked for me, in 2015. Have to check if it works the same on 2017 and 2019.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I run Visual Studio 2019 within a Virtual Box 6.0 Image based on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

I just had a similar problem. Tried:

- Clicking to reload the designer
- Cleaning my solution
- Restarting Visual Studio
- Repairing Visual Studio
- Uninstalling and re-installing Visual Studio!

It ended up being graphics related, as you mentioned.

I have hybrid graphics (Intel and NVIDIA), and was using NVIDIA for Visual Studio. Changed it to Intel and this worked.

If it helps, a screenshot of my NVIDIA control panel is below:

Before (broken):

[image: Before (NVIDIA control panel set to NVIDIA)]

After (working):

[image: After (NVIDIA control panel set to Auto-select)]

Answer (score 2):

Some people have found a file "c:\program" that causes this, often created by typo creating a log file.
Check to see if this file exists, and if so, move or delete it.

Comment: Thanks, you saved a lot of potential time taken me to fix it

Comment: I saw you made a similar comment at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/422476/view.html .  Do you have any more details? What location was this file in? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Start Visual Studio `As Administrator`~!

I had the same problem when i started working in `Team Projects`, so almost everything did not work including the designer, properties menu, debugging and so on.. (which is totally unusual for anything to cause all these problems except for Administrator Privileges issues probably in most cases).

Don't know why or what caused it, but at least it works.

Comment: Thx for your comment. I've already sovled that.. Administrator privileges was not the cause of my problem, I've tryed that as pirst possibility.. Problem was in switchable graphics card on my laptop.. most MS products have a problem with AMD part. I always have to switch card to Intel HD and it starts to work properly.. but why? Don't know, doesn't make sense..

Comment: @PetrHromek Looks like a driver problem, but anyways glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Graphics card was the problem for me. I have an external USB video from DisplayLink and when I disconnected it the problems went away. in fact it didn't return when I reconnected the displaylink.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the problem with using system brushes as `ThemeResource`. Yes this is apparently a bug like other odd bugs in MS products. So I had to comment out them until I finished my project. I don't know, maybe another factor such as my graphic hardware was not ineffective but this does not exonerate MS.