# Why does Visual Studio 2015 Designer crash with "Designer process terminated unexpectedly"?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2015, blend-2015

Does anyone know how to debug this? No matter what I do, I can't use Visual Studio 2015 Designer or Blend 2015. Both are coming up with this error:

[image]

Everything compiles and runs smoothly, but the designer doesn't work. I don't even know what `System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException` means.

Comment: Seems to be a recurring issue - you may want to try what is suggested here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/797072/designer-crashes-in-visual-studio-2013-with-system-runtime-remoting-remotingexception

Comment: Thanks 
@chue, I've seen that post before. I tried deleting ShadowCache, bins, objs, etc. Still... no good.

Comment: You need to get your machine healthy again.  Anti-malware is always the first place to start when there's trouble getting one process to talk to another.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant. I disabled all protection. Still... no good.

Comment: Are you using a MapControl by chance? I was having this issue and was able to "fix" it by commenting out my MapControl...  I googled around about it and found this from 2012 which relates to Bing Maps https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cebbcf1e-defa-4b70-b960-a8aa0a8b9d16/geeting-systemruntimeremotingremotingexception-5484-designer-process-terminated-unexpectedly?forum=bingmapswindows8.... I have to assume the same issue still exists

Comment: Hi @ShaneNeuville. No I'm not using MapControl, but good to know if I have to use it in the future.

Comment: Darn :-/ seems like a lot of things cause this error... Just opened a project this morning with no MapControl in it getting this same error :-( If figure that one out I'll check back in :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio - Designer process terminated unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001812/visual-studio-designer-process-terminated-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Figure it out. I hope this helps someone in the future.

The culprit was the *Any CPU* platform selection. When you select **x86** or **x64**, everything works :)

[image]

Comment: To anyone stumble upon this issue. Change from x86 to x64 (just change the platform) will do

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using Visual Studio 2015 **Update 2** solved the issue.

[VS2015 Update 2 link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx)