# Trouble Building Windows Universal App on Windows 10

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windowsiot

I'm trying to build a Windows Universal App (the eventual target is a Raspberry Pi 2, though I haven't even gotten to the point where I can deploy to a device).

I have followed all the instructions on the "[Get Started with Windows IoT](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/GetStarted.htm)" page (all versions are correct, Windows 10 Pro is in developer mode).  I have reinstalled Visual Studio (Community Edition 15), and -- not kidding -- done a fresh install of Windows 10 followed by Visual Studio (it needed to be done anyway).

I'm still getting the same result.

I create a brand new project: "Blank App (Universal Windows)".  I have tried .NET Framework 4.5.2 (the default) and 4.61, and I have tried unchecking the "Show telemetry in the Windows Dev Center" option.  None of this seems to make a difference.

Once I have the new project, I open `MainPage.xaml` in designer, and I get the following error in the designer window:

```
An Unhandled Exception has occurred

Details:

System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException
[9556] Designer process terminated unexpectedly!
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IIsolationDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String assemblyCodeBase, String typeName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<StartTask>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Okay, I think to myself, I can try building this app blind, working only with XAML...but then when I try to run the project (Debug, x86, Local Machine), that fails too.  First, it appears as if its bootstrapping the app, as evidenced by the big blue window:

[image: Universal App Window]

Then, after a second, I get this bizarre message that claims it can't attach a debugger (though I can see the debugger running in the background):

[image: Debugger Not Configured]

When I clear that dialog, the one behind it becomes available, which asks if I want to debug it in a new instance of Visual Studio.  When I say yes to that, a new instance of Visual Studio starts and -- it's almost comical at this point -- says this:

[image]

(If I decline to open a new debugger, the application just closes down, stopping the original debugger.)

Finally (whether I chose to open the new debugger or not), I get the following error in the original Visual Studio instance:

[image]

I would be laughing if I didn't really need to get this project underway...at this point, I'm considering abandoning WUA and going with a Linux-based approach...but I think a WUA would be much better if I could just get it to work!

Does anyone have any thoughts on what's going on here?  Again, this is a fresh install of Windows 10 and Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001812/visual-studio-designer-process-terminated-unexpectedly

Comment: I did, @miparnisari, none of the advice helped...did the re-install (twice) and tried running in admin mode.  Same problems.

Comment: Ok, have you checked the Event Log? It may have more information

Comment: Nothing obvious in the Event Log...I guess I'll start looking for non-obvioius things :(

Comment: The link I posted mentions issues with the graphic card, which one do you have?

Comment: I do have a NVIDA card, but the current version of the NVIDIA control panel does not have the settings the answer refers to....

Comment: But what graphic card do you have?

Comment: NVIDIA GeFOrce GT 640

Comment: Have you tried updating the driver? I can see in http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/96882/en-us that it was updated a couple of days ago. Check the release notes: http://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/361.43/361.43-win10-win8-win7-winvista-desktop-release-notes.pdf

Comment: I installed Windows 10 from scratch today. The first thing I did was install the latest video drivers, so yes, I have the latest.

Comment: Do you have the latest VS tools for Windows 10? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/dn913721.aspx

Comment: Just installed those, @John; same results.

Comment: Just to clarify, @EthanBrown did the app deploy successfully? You can check by trying to start it from the start menu. If it can start form the start menu, then it seems like it is a debugger launch issue. Otherwise, seems like a deploy/activation issue.

Comment: I haven't tried to deploy it yet.  I just want to be able to run it in the debugger, and to have the XAML designer work.  It's going to be hell to build an app without being able to do those two things.

Comment: Sorry, when I say deploy, I mean local deploy (which VS will do for you when you hit F5). Since you have already hit F5, the App *should* be in your %ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps. You can check from Admin cmd.exe only.

Comment: I don't see anything that looks like my app in `%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps`....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99370/discussion-between-john-and-ethan-brown).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known issue in Visual Studio Update 1 where a Universal App Project fails to activate if its solution is on a drive other than the "C" drive.

Workaround is to move your project to the "C" drive.