# VS 2015: "Designer process terminated unexpectedly!"

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xaml, designer

When I'm creating Universal Windows Application and then making double click on "MainPage.xaml" file in project, designer begins to load, but at the end I always have the same issue:

> System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException , Designer process
>   terminated unexpectedly!

Already 3 days I try to fix it, using all advises from internet, but nothing helps me. 
What can I do?  Will be really appreciate for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio - Designer process terminated unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001812/visual-studio-designer-process-terminated-unexpectedly)